# Plot image in 2d plain and apply operations like translation/rotation and reflection

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I want to read an image on Matlab and on 2d plain perform changes of its coordinates as I would have done on a graph

```
img = imread('img.png');
sz = size(img);
imshow(img);
```

I am very new to matlab and do not understand much too. I know that imread will get 3d matrix. First 2 with original values
and the last for RGB.
Those are color values and I do not thin that can be used to apply rotation or translation
Below is the example oof what I actually want to do.
[image]

To translate the general formula is

[image]

Now I donot know how to get actual x,y coordinates and how will I be doing rotaions